# Deployment to Heroku success but when I open the URL, I get a blank page with the word "Error" on it?

Tags: heroku, deployment

I am deploying my `Heroku web app,` but am running into an issue. It deploys successfully on Heroku, but then when I try to open the web app/URL, I simply get a blank page with the word `"Error"` on it.

Here are the logs from Heroku, any ideas what could get going wrong?:

```
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.59.0 to 7.59.2.
2021-11-24T10:49:32.042026+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.20.123 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:49:32 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DashLinkPreviews/5.1;)"
2021-11-24T10:49:32.042318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=e5293635-8393-4174-ab0a-e3bc9b002098 fwd="52.89.103.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=488 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:49:32.066448+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.23.180 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:49:32 +0000] "HEAD /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.3.18"
2021-11-24T10:49:32.066666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/twitter_login/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=14607c62-9237-4da5-9f10-fbeab9579597 fwd="52.89.103.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=144ms status=302 bytes=248 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:49:32.482378+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.36.190 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:49:32 +0000] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 364 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DashLinkPreviews/5.1;)"
2021-11-24T10:49:32.482595+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter_login/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=e88d2332-b22f-4d65-87c3-6ab092eda352 fwd="52.89.103.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=166ms status=302 bytes=612 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:49:32.916388+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.13.177 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:49:32 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DashLinkPreviews/5.1;)"
2021-11-24T10:49:32.916515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=20042fec-c958-4bbe-89d2-00f65ba028bf fwd="52.89.103.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=488 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:49:33.377172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter_login/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=6f108754-d1c1-4462-b881-e7b36c8fdbe0 fwd="52.89.103.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=158ms status=302 bytes=612 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:49:33.377192+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.149 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:49:33 +0000] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 364 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DashLinkPreviews/5.1;)"
2021-11-24T10:51:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user patrick_chong@hotmail.co.uk
2021-11-24T10:52:15.595446+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2982047e by user patrick_chong@hotmail.co.uk
2021-11-24T10:52:15.595446+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user patrick_chong@hotmail.co.uk
2021-11-24T10:52:16.184288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-11-24T10:52:16.558277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-11-24T10:52:17.303889+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-11-24T10:52:17.427599+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:17 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-11-24T10:52:17.427614+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:17 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-11-24T10:52:17.427615+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-11-24T10:52:17.430015+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:17 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-11-24T10:52:17.527907+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-11-24T10:52:17.662882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-11-24T10:52:20.111502+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-11-24T10:52:21.319042+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:21 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-11-24T10:52:21.319607+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:21 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:28290 (4)
2021-11-24T10:52:21.319669+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:21 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-11-24T10:52:21.322754+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:21 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-11-24T10:52:21.399802+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 10:52:21 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-11-24T10:52:21.743544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-11-24T10:52:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-11-24T10:52:32.574053+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.43.202 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:52:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 222 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-11-24T10:52:32.574861+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=9a1a55fb-86e3-4e35-96e8-5f8090d237fe fwd="185.69.144.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=446 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:52:32.802757+00:00 app[web.1]: <Response [401]>
2021-11-24T10:52:32.804261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=3cee9316-b084-42ef-8636-c5b050264bc3 fwd="185.69.144.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=92ms status=200 bytes=181 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:52:32.805749+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.31.245 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:52:32 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 200 14 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-11-24T10:54:35.365273+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:54:35 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:54:35.367226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=3b1f34ec-c249-4346-9670-729ba1656693 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=302 bytes=488 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:54:35.821123+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:54:35 +0000] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 364 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:54:35.822983+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter_login/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=b4d69734-2354-4b5d-84bd-cd806aa26953 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=213ms status=302 bytes=612 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:54:38.917827+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:54:38 +0000] "GET /twitter_login/twitter/authorized?oauth_token=Jv_wVgAAAAABRQePAAABfVGVQMs&oauth_verifier=2YDe0VP1LE1XcO5EIDnGmbSVOd6iY7D5 HTTP/1.1" 302 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:54:38.919403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter_login/twitter/authorized?oauth_token=Jv_wVgAAAAABRQePAAABfVGVQMs&oauth_verifier=2YDe0VP1LE1XcO5EIDnGmbSVOd6iY7D5" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=53b9b036-4c30-40d9-9f68-3866e1cb1bdc fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=554ms status=302 bytes=754 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:54:39.139120+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:54:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 222 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:54:39.141093+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=547ed339-97a3-4a7c-b705-ca6d2a7d4521 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=446 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:54:39.504505+00:00 app[web.1]: <Response [200]>
2021-11-24T10:54:39.626922+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:54:39 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 200 28494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:54:39.628757+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=8c62f1a4-daa9-4a23-b3d6-794c6cedb093 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=268ms status=200 bytes=28664 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:54:40.190311+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:54:40 +0000] "GET /assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com/twitter" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:54:40.192314+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=2cbb0178-b50a-4bf2-aced-03f88cd77c36 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:54:40.802549+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:54:40 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com/twitter" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:54:40.804396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=490ef232-d3fc-4b79-99e4-9e2f4b6c6b4e fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:03.133764+00:00 app[web.1]: <Response [200]>
2021-11-24T10:55:03.312950+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:03 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 200 28558 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:03.314591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=dae53511-b343-45b9-90e2-ceee62e264cf fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=363ms status=200 bytes=28728 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:03.833838+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:03 +0000] "GET /assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com/twitter" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:03.835911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=9a03f7b4-ede8-40e8-89ce-67faa4eb4135 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:04.070467+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.82.236 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:04 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com/twitter" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:04.072305+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=5999ece6-0e4f-49d4-b31d-0b6241926b11 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:25.030182+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.95 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:25 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:25.030289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=fbf9fc5b-0ec9-43c0-8205-53dfce39e3e3 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=488 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:25.400682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter_login/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=8a0578b7-5cd2-4953-bd2b-d103c0917358 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=162ms status=302 bytes=612 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:25.400773+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.95 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:25 +0000] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 364 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:33.987022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter_login/twitter/authorized?oauth_token=Na9QiAAAAAABRQePAAABfVGWAok&oauth_verifier=15S65hCtV5LE9VmTrKBxM2YJaX1Ba5SZ" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=6b350b6a-87fa-4c8e-9037-491d4d6c6b8b fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=406ms status=302 bytes=754 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:33.987120+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.95 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:33 +0000] "GET /twitter_login/twitter/authorized?oauth_token=Na9QiAAAAAABRQePAAABfVGWAok&oauth_verifier=15S65hCtV5LE9VmTrKBxM2YJaX1Ba5SZ HTTP/1.1" 302 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:34.217622+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.95 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 222 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:34.217825+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=0efdcaf2-5113-42ce-b69d-aaa6478f3daa fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=302 bytes=446 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:35.110572+00:00 app[web.1]: <Response [200]>
2021-11-24T10:55:35.239835+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.95 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:35 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 200 28567 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:35.240115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=98de4b71-04a6-454a-84b6-1135c20be181 fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=292ms status=200 bytes=28737 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:35.876216+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.95 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:35 +0000] "GET /assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com/twitter" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:35.877387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=14333b78-c492-4af2-84bb-400c7f972f6e fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:55:37.587393+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.95 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:55:37 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com/twitter" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
2021-11-24T10:55:37.587494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=dc855a6f-fd9a-4bac-b58d-da98f722ccdc fwd="103.132.244.181" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:57:52.929244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=0d7e76a3-4f2c-47b9-ac95-63e4a03c9469 fwd="34.217.253.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=238 protocol=https
2021-11-24T10:57:52.930464+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.8.241 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:57:52 +0000] "HEAD /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.3.18"
2021-11-24T10:57:53.388944+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.86.74 - - [24/Nov/2021:10:57:53 +0000] "HEAD /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.3.18"
2021-11-24T10:57:53.389860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/twitter_login/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=7065706d-356f-4cb9-b5b0-1a4f05cf073d fwd="34.217.253.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=170ms status=302 bytes=248 protocol=https
2021-11-24T11:19:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user patrick_chong@hotmail.co.uk
2021-11-24T11:19:25.539500+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 71d3eda0 by user patrick_chong@hotmail.co.uk
2021-11-24T11:19:25.539500+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user patrick_chong@hotmail.co.uk
2021-11-24T11:19:26.083179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-11-24T11:19:26.149732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-11-24T11:19:27.103543+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-11-24T11:19:27.154992+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-11-24T11:19:27.155835+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-11-24T11:19:27.156773+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-11-24T11:19:27.259037+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-11-24T11:19:27.883321+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-11-24T11:19:29.212075+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-11-24T11:19:31.173921+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-11-24T11:19:31.174465+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:52315 (4)
2021-11-24T11:19:31.174523+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-11-24T11:19:31.178139+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:31 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-11-24T11:19:31.230813+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-24 11:19:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-11-24T11:19:31.835296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-11-24T11:19:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-11-24T11:19:40.739464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=27a313c0-7539-4053-9c5a-5e5a8b05085e fwd="185.69.144.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=446 protocol=https
2021-11-24T11:19:40.739795+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.83.184 - - [24/Nov/2021:11:19:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 222 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
2021-11-24T11:19:40.949308+00:00 app[web.1]: <Response [401]>
2021-11-24T11:19:40.950472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/twitter" host=twitter-web-scrapper95823.herokuapp.com request_id=b9d01f77-76ae-4ec0-8285-831481a22ee4 fwd="185.69.144.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=93ms status=200 bytes=181 protocol=https
2021-11-24T11:19:40.951162+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.83.184 - - [24/Nov/2021:11:19:40 +0000] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 200 14 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15
```

"

Do let me know if I should add any more details around the code or deployment. Not sure if this helps, but when I try to run the app on my local drive I get the same error. I also tested it with different twitter accounts, but I run into the same error each time.

To add some context, I am using the Twitter API to scrape the top 20 tweets of the user.

When I run the code on my **local terminal**, I get the following:

```
(base) patrickchong@Patricks-MacBook-Pro TwitterWebScrapper % flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:38] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
OAuth 1 request token error: Token request failed with code 403, response was '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>'.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:38] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:38] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
OAuth 1 request token error: Token request failed with code 403, response was '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>'.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
OAuth 1 request token error: Token request failed with code 403, response was '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>'.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
OAuth 1 request token error: Token request failed with code 403, response was '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>'.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
OAuth 1 request token error: Token request failed with code 403, response was '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>'.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:39] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
OAuth 1 request token error: Token request failed with code 403, response was '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>'.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:40] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:40] "GET /twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
OAuth 1 request token error: Token request failed with code 403, response was '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>'.
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2021 14:41:40] "GET /twitter_login/twitter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Comment: Just a blank page with the word "error" doesn't sound like a Heroku error page; it sounds like something in your application. Heroku's HTTP 500 error page says something like "application error" and tells you how to check your logs. What is _supposed_ to display in the browser? Scraping Twitter doesn't sound like it needs a UI at all...

Comment: "when I try to run the app on my local drive I get the same error"—then this is unrelated to your deployment, and possibly unrelated to Heroku at all. How are you running locally?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I am running it locally through Flask run - if this is what you are asking

Comment: And when you say the error may be to do with my app, do you mean that it is the code that could be the issue?

Comment: Because when a friend of mine runs it using his Twitter account, it seems to work fine but using my twitter account, and a new twitter account that I created for this sole purpose, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a Heroku problem. Remember, the code is also failing _on your local machine_. It's something with the code, your configuration, etc. What errors do you see in the terminal when you run `flask run`?

Comment: No error, let me add the logs to the above